# How to setup multiple environments (dev\stage\production) with elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I need to do the following

Change environment variables according to the published env. Set Set up cron jobs according to the dev. I I would like to run just 1 command line "eb deploy dev" or something similar.

Comment: This is entirely possible with ElasticBeanstalk. What have you tried and what problems are you running into?

Comment: @Brian - 
Change the DB string for example (and many other things like that, api keys etc...)
If you use enviorment variables they will be reset after the deploy
If i use .env file its not on git so it wont deploy
If i use a config file, how to change it before deploy

Answer (score 1):

### Use `setenv`

You can set environment variables with `setenv`. These will then be remembered for that environment.

More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html

### Example

For example, suppose you have created an EB environment called 'staging' and you want to set the variable `DB` to 'localhost', you can use:

`eb setenv DB=localhost -e staging`

### Crons

Now that you have a different environment variables, you can check them in a script etc. to decide if the cron should be set up.

Note that the crons may not actually have access to your environment variables so you need to set those again for the cron while setting up the cron.

Comment: Unfortunately its more complex then that.
I have something like 6 env vars and its pretty long to change them all and also i need something to setup the cron job etc.
I will post my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem, it took some time to setup but now i can do all the changes with 1 command line.

Make your own folder with all the files for all the environments.
In .ebextensions folder setup empty config files for eb.
npm runs a script named "deploy.js" together with the flag of the specific env.
The script will do the following

- copy the requested env data to the empty files according to the env
- git stash the changes of .ebextensions folder (eb deploys using git)
- eb use env
- eb deploy

So now i can tun npm run deploy:dev and everything runs